# Is it possible to set the timeout for Ajax-Requests within PhantomJS

Tags: ajax, phantomjs

I am doing some stuff with ajax-Requests within PhantomJS. Unfortunately there is a 30s timeout for ajax-Requests within a PhantomJS-webpage.

I've been trying to set the `timeout`property in the `$.ajax`-settings. Unfortunately this seems to get ignored completely. Same goes for:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 120000
});
```

Then there is the [ExtJS](https://ahlearns.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/ext-js-4-override-timeouts/) framework extension. Unfortunately `Ext`is undefined within the PhantomJS WebPage. So this does not work aswell.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First, why do you want to quadruple the timeout? Second, how did you try to use `$.ajaxSetup`. I mean when did you trigger it in PhantomJS? And when is the first request sent that you care about (before DOMReady/before onload/after onload)?

Comment: There are certain web-pages which take a VERY long time to compute a response. I will adjust a correct timeout afterwards, the 120s are just for testing purposes.
I create a WebPage and inject jQuery to this page. I use $.ajaxSetup within this webpage.
I care about every ajax request I have explicitly sent. Usually this is after page load.

Answer (score 2):

Since `$.ajaxSetup` sets the *default* values, it cannot be used to override existing "setups" or `ajax` requests that set `timeout`. It seems, you can override with [`$.ajaxPrefilter`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/).

According to the comments, this has to be done before the page load. I assume the first ajax request is not yet sent when DOMContentLoaded is triggered.

```
page.onLoadStarted = function(){
    page.evaluate(function(){
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
                options.timeout = 120000;
            });
        }, true);
    });
};
```

Comment: I haven't actually checked that PhantomJS supports `addEventListener` and the `DOMContentLoaded` event

Comment: Thanks Artjom, unfortunately your suggestion does not work. :( Any other ideas?